# Can ubuntu 20.4 run on single core 2.2 GHz 64bit processor?

Tags: compatibility, system-requirements

I have a Fuijitsu Siemens Amilo notebook li 3710.It has 4GB ram.It has an Intel celeron 900 processor which is 2.20 GHz single core 64 bit processor. Hard disk space is more than enough.Will it run Ubuntu 20.4 hassle free?

Comment: I see no reason why not.

Comment: But I would recommend Xubuntu for this hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, im sure it works, i have a Intel Celeron with 1.1Ghz (Dual core). It freezes, on swapping due to bad configuration, but im sure that's my fault.